# How to use a method to populate a Hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, hash

I am working on a challenge that requests I create 2 classes:

```
Bank
Person
```

My goal is to be able to have `Bank` and `Person` communicate with each other.  I have that working up until I have to manipulate **account balances** with the methods below. but I am having trouble creating bank accounts to work with the test input code/output that was given at the bottom of the post.

I have decided to initialize an instance of a hash

```
@account_balances = {}
```

My goal is to add a bank account with zero balance to the hash every time I use the Bank class method

```
open_account(customer)
```

Can anyone help?  I might be barking up the wrong tree with the Hash idea....but I have tried other ideas and they didn't work properly.  I figure if I can create the Hash to store the individual accounts, I can use the deposit/withdraw methods to manipulate them.

**Bank Class**

Comment: Calling `Class.new` is highly irregular and is reserved for situations where you are dynamically composing a class. Better is declaring your classes like `class Person` where, if necessary, you can define any methods inside that block. It looks like you've declared `Bank` twice here, that should be producing an error.

Comment: I removed that odd `Bank = Class.new` stuff, not sure what that was all about.

Comment: @tadman Oddly, OP is doing that; not sure what their intent was so I edited it out.

Comment: Thanks Dave...forgive me for being a newbie... the code has been working thus far in irb, so i didn't notice the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside initialize:

```
@bank = bank
@customers = {}
puts "#{@bank} bank was just created."
```

And then inside `open_account(customer)`

```
@customers[customer] = 0
puts "#{customer.name}, thanks for opening an account at #{@bank}!"
```

Comment: ok, thanks....i'll fiddle with that.  I hope that works. A main part of this array/hash is that I need an account name and it has to be set to zero.....and later be able to be adjusted with the deposit/withdraw methods

Comment: Sorry I misread - try this. @customers is now a hash, with the customer object as the key, and the balance as the associated value

Comment: user2635088...Thanks for our help...i'm banging my head against the wall with this.  I tried that.  it doesn't produce an error, but doesn't populate the hash either...huh?

Comment: This is my output from IRB

`2.0.0-p451 :154 > chase.customers`
 => {#<Person:0x007f9c913fbf08 @name="Sam", @cash=500>=>0}

Comment: You also need an attr_reader for customers - i.e. `attr_reader :bank, :customers`

Comment: exactly!...silly me.  Now I have to figure out a way to iterate over the Hash so I can add and subtract from individual accounts using the deposit and withdraw methods.